# Vue + Vuetify - test:unit cannot see the v-alert message value

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my component template I have a v-alert vuetify sub-component

```
        <v-alert dismissible @input="closeAlert()" @type="msgTypeContactForm" v-model="msgStatusContactForm">{{ msgValueContactForm }}</v-alert>
```

using the following data

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      msgStatusContactForm: false,
      msgTypeContactForm: "",
      msgValueContactForm: ""
    };
  },
```

on submitting the form, when an error is raised , I set these data

```
  catch (err) {
       this.msgTypeContactForm = "error";
       this.msgValueContactForm = this.$i18n.t("lang.views.home.contactForm.post_error");
       this.msgStatusContactForm = true;
```

This is running fine, the alert is correctly displayed with the correct type and value ..

However in the component unit test ,  the alert properties and value are not updated in the template

```
       it("should not sendMessage - invalid form", async () => {
           ...
           wrapper = mount(ContactForm, options);
           const contactForm = wrapper.find("form");
           ...
           const btnSubmit = wrapper.find("#btnSubmit");
           btnSubmit.trigger("click");
           await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
           // then
           setTimeout(() => {
             expect(wrapper.vm.validForm).toEqual(false);
             expect(wrapper.vm.msgStatusContactForm).toEqual(true);
             expect(wrapper.vm.msgTypeContactForm).toEqual("error");
           }, 2000);
           await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
           const alert = wrapper.find(".v-alert");
           console.log("INVALID FORM ALERT: ", alert.html());
         })
```

console.log tests/unit/ContactForm.spec.js:383
    INVALID FORM ALERT:  cancel

the alert should be displayed and the type set and message value present in the html output ....

I don't know where I am wrong in my test ?  any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED..

It's a matter of handling async/await function...  in my component

```
submitForm: async function() {
  ....
```

So I use flush-promises in my test

```
 yarn add -D flush-promises
```

then

```
import flushPromises from "flush-promises";
...

it("should not sendMessage - invalid form", async () => {
 ...
 wrapper = mount(ContactForm, options);
 ...
 // then
const btnSubmit = wrapper.find("#btnSubmit");
btnSubmit.trigger("click");
await flushPromises();
...
const alert = wrapper.find(".v-alert");
console.log("INVALID FORM ALERT: ", alert.html());
```

Then I can see the DOM updated

```
<div class="v-alert error" style=""><div>One or more fields are invalid. Please, review your input and submit</div><a class="v-alert__dismissible"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon v-icon--right material-icons theme--light">cancel</i></a></div>
```